# Is there a way to add multiple strings to a Text object? (Zelle Graphics)

Tags: python, zelle-graphics

I'm trying to create a Text object with multiple strings using the Zelle Graphics library, but it seems to accept only a single string argument. This is how I set it up:

```
text = Text(Point(250, 250), "You have", x, "remaining")
```

This is the desired output (as displayed in the graphics window):

"You have x remaining"

Comment: Can you please add an example and desired output? It's not that very clear with just the question.

Comment: Have you had a look at string formatting?

Comment: Since you've not provided any pseudo code, desired output or example, I am assuming this is all about formatting as the other user mentions in the comment above. Well I'll suggest just go through basic formatting a string in python. 

https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You neglected to explain that you are using the `graphics` module by John Zelle. I know that is in the tag, but it is better to be a little bit more explicit. Even experts cannot be expected to know automatically about every library out there.

The `Text` class in that module has a constructor with the following signature:

```
def __init__(self, p, text):
```

meaning you have to pass it a `Point` object and exactly one string. That means you can't do this:

```
text = Text(Point(250, 250), "You have", x, "remaining")
```

but you can do

```
text = Text(Point(250, 250), f"You have {x} remaining")
```

in Python 3.7 or

```
text = Text(Point(250, 250), "You have {x} remaining".format(x=x))
```

in earlier versions.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand from your question you would like something like this:

```
x = 4
print("You have %s of these remaining" % x)

# Output: You have 4 of these remaining
```

You can think of %s as a place holder, and you asign its value after the % outside of the string.

Another way of doing it would be like this:

```
x = 4
print("You have " + str(x) + " of these remaining")
```

This would print the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

String formatting is what you are referring to.
.format should be good [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)